# SSSD Active Directory Integration with VSFTPD

Tags: networking, server, vsftpd, active-directory, sssd

My goal is to setup VSFTPD with AD authentication via SSSD. I ran through the article on Ubuntu's website here https://ubuntu.com/server/docs/service-sssd. I was able to join my domain, however authentication still doesn't work and running getent passwd myuser@mydomain.local returns nothing. These are all the default files generated when joining a domain. Is there something the documentation is missing or a log that could help?

SSSD.CONF

```
[sssd]
domains = mydomain.local
config_file_version = 2
services = nss, pam

[domain/mydomain.local]
enumerate = true
default_shell = /bin/bash
krb5_store_password_if_offline = True
cache_credentials = True
krb5_realm = MYDOMAIN.LOCAL
realmd_tags = manages-system joined-with-adcli
id_provider = ad
fallback_homedir = /home/%u@%d
ad_domain = mydomain.local
use_fully_qualified_names = True
ldap_id_mapping = True
access_provider = ad
```

KRB5.conf

```
[libdefaults]
        default_realm = MYDOMAIN.local

        fcc-mit-ticketflags = true

[realms]
        ATHENA.MIT.EDU = {
                kdc = kerberos.mit.edu
                kdc = kerberos-1.mit.edu
                kdc = kerberos-2.mit.edu:88
                admin_server = kerberos.mit.edu
                default_domain = mit.edu
        }
        ZONE.MIT.EDU = {
                kdc = casio.mit.edu
                kdc = seiko.mit.edu
                admin_server = casio.mit.edu
        }
        CSAIL.MIT.EDU = {
                admin_server = kerberos.csail.mit.edu
                default_domain = csail.mit.edu
        }
        IHTFP.ORG = {
                kdc = kerberos.ihtfp.org
                admin_server = kerberos.ihtfp.org
        }
        1TS.ORG = {
                kdc = kerberos.1ts.org
                admin_server = kerberos.1ts.org
        }
        ANDREW.CMU.EDU = {
                admin_server = kerberos.andrew.cmu.edu
                default_domain = andrew.cmu.edu
        }
        CS.CMU.EDU = {
                kdc = kerberos-1.srv.cs.cmu.edu
                kdc = kerberos-2.srv.cs.cmu.edu
                kdc = kerberos-3.srv.cs.cmu.edu
                admin_server = kerberos.cs.cmu.edu
        }
        DEMENTIA.ORG = {
                kdc = kerberos.dementix.org
                kdc = kerberos2.dementix.org
                admin_server = kerberos.dementix.org
        }
        stanford.edu = {
                kdc = krb5auth1.stanford.edu
                kdc = krb5auth2.stanford.edu
                kdc = krb5auth3.stanford.edu
                master_kdc = krb5auth1.stanford.edu
                admin_server = krb5-admin.stanford.edu
                default_domain = stanford.edu
        }
        UTORONTO.CA = {
                kdc = kerberos1.utoronto.ca
                kdc = kerberos2.utoronto.ca
                kdc = kerberos3.utoronto.ca
                admin_server = kerberos1.utoronto.ca
                default_domain = utoronto.ca
        }

[domain_realm]
        .mit.edu = ATHENA.MIT.EDU
        mit.edu = ATHENA.MIT.EDU
        .media.mit.edu = MEDIA-LAB.MIT.EDU
        media.mit.edu = MEDIA-LAB.MIT.EDU
        .csail.mit.edu = CSAIL.MIT.EDU
        csail.mit.edu = CSAIL.MIT.EDU
        .whoi.edu = ATHENA.MIT.EDU
        whoi.edu = ATHENA.MIT.EDU
        .stanford.edu = stanford.edu
        .slac.stanford.edu = SLAC.STANFORD.EDU
        .toronto.edu = UTORONTO.CA
        .utoronto.ca = UTORONTO.CA
```

NSS

```
# /etc/nsswitch.conf
#
# Example configuration of GNU Name Service Switch functionality.
# If you have the `glibc-doc-reference' and `info' packages installed, try:
# `info libc "Name Service Switch"' for information about this file.

passwd:         files systemd sss
group:          files systemd sss
shadow:         files sss
gshadow:        files

hosts:          files dns
networks:       files

protocols:      db files
services:       db files sss
ethers:         db files
rpc:            db files

netgroup:       nis sss
sudoers:        files sss
automount:      sss
```